# Date input string mm/dd/yyyy doesn't show in Mobile phone

Tags: string, date, input, mobile

I have this issue.. here is what I have in my form for the date input box:

```
<input id="date" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text" name="dob" data-date-format="MM DD YYYY" onfocus="(this.type = 'date')" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required>
```

It works well on desktops/laptops, but when you go to mobile or tablets and tap/touch the input field which has Date of Birth it becomes blank and you have to tap/touch it again and you get the calendar as far as I can tell, which works, but I'm trying to get it to show mm/dd/yyyy the first time you tap/touch on Date of Birth in the mobile not just on desk/laps and that is the issue. This is a bit of my css for the date portion of it that I'm using:

```
    form input[type="text"],
    form input[type="email"],
    form input[type="password"],
    form input[type="date"],    
    form select,
    form textarea {
        -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-appearance: none;                                   
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        background: #e8e8e8;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 4px;
        line-height: 1.25em;
        padding: 0.75em 1em 0.75em 1em;
}

        form input[type="text"]:focus,
        form input[type="email"]:focus,
        form input[type="password"]:focus,
        form input[type="date"]:focus,                      
        form select:focus,
        form textarea:focus {
            background: #f0f0f0;
    }
```

but, as you can see I use id="date" in the form. I would like to keep the placeholder so it continues to show Date of Birth on it. If you have any suggestions please let me know and it's greatly appreciated. Sorry for posting in answers, my fault. Thanks for the help.

Btw I did try to manipulate the css in a few different ways but to no avail.